# How to program select by attribute unique values using ArcGIS silverlight API?

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api, select-by-attribute

I'd like to create a select by attribute window in my webGIS using silverlight api . this is like select by attribute in arcgis desktop . i create  select layer combobox ( cbolayers)and select fields combobox(cbofields) to select fields of selected layer  . the application needs a listbox to list unique values of selected field like arcgis desktop unique values listbox . i surf in the internet but couldn't find any good source to help me about How can i create unique values listbox .could you please help me about this subject?